# Trouble with linq query on a Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Consider the following . . .

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> myData;
```

I would like to keep only the outer entries where the **inner** `int > 1`.

```
myData= myData.Select(c => c.Value.Where(i => i.Value > 1));
```

. . . throws a conversion error.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The answer @Saeed gave is doing great, but however I now need something additional.  I need the outer Dictionary to only contain entries where the inner Dictionary has more than 1 entry.  (Every time I think I've got it, I don't.  And I'm sure it something I should be seeing!)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by **the** inner `int` (singular!)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cast it to dictionary, Also you can simply use anonymous type instead of its exact type.

```
myData= myData
             .Select(c => new {Key = c.Key,
                           Value = c.Value
                           .Where(i => i.Value > 1)
                           .ToDictionary(y=>y.Key, y=>y.Value)})
             .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);
```

**Update:** After doing this, for your additional requirement do:

```
myData = myData.Where(x=>x.Value.Count() > 1).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: closer (i think), but still not right `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>' could be found`

Comment: that definitley looks much better!  LinqPad shows me that it compiles, now I just need to test the results.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @Saeed.  I added an additional requirement to the OP.  (Sorry and thanks.)

Comment: @AlanLarimer, I don't know I got your new requirement truly or not, but with something similar to my update part you can do it.

Comment: PERFECT!  Thanks again.  I don't know what I was missing something that simple.  (Too many hours methinks.)

Answer (score 5):

There is no outer dictionary where *the* `int` is greater than 1, because each outer dictionary "contains" as many integers as there are in its inner dictionary.

If you want to keep outer dictionaries where at least one `int` is greater than 1:

```
myData.Select(d => d.Value.Any(p => p.Value > 1));
```

If you want to keep outer dictionaries where all `int`s are greater than 1:

```
myData.Select(d => d.Value.All(p => p.Value > 1));
```

Comment: Current problem is casting issue, Also I don't think OP looks for what you offered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble navigating your dictionaries, maybe the thing to do is get rid of them!

```
var flattened = 
  from kvp1 in myData
  let s1 = kvp1.Key
  from kvp2 in kvp1.Value
  let s2 = kvp2.Key
  let i = kvp2.Value
  select new { s1, s2, i };
```

Now there's a nice flat collection that you should be easily able to filter to what you want.